# PostgreSQL - Violate foreign key on purpose

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, insert

I have an app **1.0** that uses a database called let's say `foo` of at least 150 tables filled with data. I have upgraded the app to **3.0** and now I also have a database called `foo2` which has almost the same tables and columns as `foo`. I can't use the app **3.0** with `foo` because of a bunch of new tables with views and new basic data. I tried migrating the data from `foo` to `foo2` but failed because of the foreign keys constraint (I have like 10 fkeys almost each table). I only need to import about 15 tables of important data from `foo` to `foo2`.

Example : I want to import a product with the same columns into the `product table` of `foo2`. The product is referencing to a `category_id`, `warehouse_id`, `account_id` `partner_id` and this partner is referencing to a `company_id` and this company is referencing to a `country_id` and so on. I can't add the product because I have no `partner_id` in `foo2` yet. The same goes for adding partners, companies, countries, etc.

I know I could probably start importing data from the root and go on but like I said, I would have 336 tables to go through which is a LOT of work for 15 tables.

So I was wondering if there's a way to ignore temporarily the fkeys constraints until all of my data are imported even if the fkeys point to a non existing id for a short while and then check for integrity problems and adjust values?

Comment: Are the tables already all created before you start inserting the data?

Comment: Yes they are. The App3.0 took care of creating the 336 basic tables which include those mentioned above. FYI, the App1.0 and 3.0 are in fact Odoo 8 and 10 Community on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Another question - are the `INSERT` statements in a single file without any `COMMIT` statements in?

Comment: Assuming you using at least PostgreSQL 9.1, you can use `ALTER TABLE <tbl> DISABLE TRIGGER ALL`, execute your imports, then reenable the trigger. A major warning though: you can have logically corrupt or orphaned records because the FK trigger couldn't validate the data being loaded. You would need to handle the data consistency issues from the application side (eg. in your SQL). See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: @bma disabling triggers won't affect FK in any way I believe.

Comment: @PhilippeChampigny consider using `INITIALLY DEFERRED` FK and one transaction population

Comment: @bma Disabling and re-enabling the triggers back after the INSERT works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @VaoTsun I'll have a look at this too thanks.

Comment: @VaoTsun The command I supplied does indeed disable the FK's. I encourage you to try the command to confirm (or disprove of course). The doc link I provided has more details if you are curious.